# Publishing fixed and random effects in one model

Tags: reference-request, paneldata, fixed-effects

I am a health economist working with panel data for a paper I am working on, I use Hausman tests to determine if I should use fixed or random effects estimators in my analysis. For some outcomes random effects are supported, for others fixed are. For the main table of results in my paper would it be acceptable to report the results of the fixed effects models for those outcomes that the Hausman suggests should use a fixed effects estimator and the results of the random effects estimator for those outcomes that a random effects estimator is suggested for?

Are there any examples of this approach in the literature?

Comment: What do you mean by "for some outcomes"? It appears that you use more than one sample, and you estimate them separately?

Comment: Currie, J., Duque, V., & Garfinkel, I. (2015). The Great Recession and mothers' health. The Economic Journal, 125(588), F311-F346. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4871274/pdf/nihms782761.pdf) have an analysis similar to my own, from page 19 onwards you will see that the authors also investigate multiple health outcomes and behaviors with the same list of covariates. I conduct a similar analysis across several combinations of waves, i.e. self-rated health and identical covariates in waves 1 and 2, waves 2 and 3, waves 1 and 3 and waves 1, 2 and 3